# XML-RPC .net standard

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core, reflection.emit

I tried to port http://xml-rpc.net/ to .NET Standard class library.
This works and I can run an application using this library on a rapsberry PI running Windows 10 IOT.
At least I can debug it. When I try to run the app without VS attached it crashes.

When I try to compile it in release mode I get a number of error messages:

```
10>  Generating System.Reflection.DispatchProxy proxy code.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildAssembly(Type, string, string, AssemblyBuilderAccess)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildAssembly(Type, string, string, AssemblyBuilderAccess)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethods(TypeBuilder, IEnumerable<XmlRpcProxyGen.MethodData>)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildAssembly(Type, string, string, AssemblyBuilderAccess)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess)' in assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.LocalBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.ParameterBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.Label' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildMethod(TypeBuilder, string, string, IReadOnlyList<string>, Type[], bool, Type, bool)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TypeBuilder.DefineMethod(string, MethodAttributes, Type, Type[])' in assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildBeginMethods(TypeBuilder, IEnumerable<XmlRpcProxyGen.MethodData>)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TypeBuilder.DefineMethod(string, MethodAttributes, Type, Type[])' in assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildEndMethods(TypeBuilder, IEnumerable<XmlRpcProxyGen.MethodData>)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TypeBuilder.DefineMethod(string, MethodAttributes, Type, Type[])' in assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.ConstructorBuilder' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildConstructor(TypeBuilder, Type, string)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildConstructor(TypeBuilder, Type, string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes, CallingConventions, Type[])' in assembly 'System.Reflection.Emit'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
```

Moving the source files directly to my IOT app and adding System.Reflection.Emit nuget package brings the same result.

Am I missing something?

Or if System.Reflection.Emit has a problem - does anyone know a XML-RPC library which is not as dynamic as xml-rpc.net - but at least supports multicall and event?

Comment: I can't help but change could be on the horizon with the release of .NET Standard  2.1 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/05/announcing-net-standard-2-1/

Answer (score 1):

1. The warning messages that you posted indicate that your build target environment is incompatible with the classes you've chosen
   (XmlRpcProxyGen and Reflection). Windows IoT is a scaled-down OS from regular Windows and does not contain all the features of other 
   Windows versions. See [IotCorePortingTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/iotcoreportingtool) for a tool you can use to identify missing api's
2. With regards to another XML-RPC library, there is ATLServer available with [w3pi](https://w3pi.info) web-server however it requires knowledge of programming in c++ and gets extremely complicated compared to .NET

   Basically you would be creating a fairly large web-application that is statically-linked to MSXML 6.0 (as this is the only msxml library that 
   runs on Windows IoT Core). The multi-call functionality could be implemented manually using [ATLServer soap dynamic arrays](https://books.google.ca/books?id=6W8aD9KWFr0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q&f=false) , while the event functionality could theoretically be built using an HTTP/2 Push frame via the ATLServer TransmitFile method, described [on w3pi's ATLServer information page](https://w3pi.info/www/atlserver.srf#http2-push)